# Svelte typescript error for event Listener

Tags: typescript, svelte

Following [this tutorial](https://svelte.dev/examples/actions-pannable), I am trying to replicate the same in typescript.

```
export function pannable(node: Node) {
    let x: number;
    let y: number;
    function handleMousedown(event: MouseEvent) {
        x = event.clientX;
        y = event.clientY;
        node.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('panstart', {
                detail: { x, y }
            })
        );
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMousemove);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseup);
    }

   // ...

    node.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMousedown);
```

I get this error:

```
Argument of type '(event:MouseEvent) =>void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListnerOrEventListenerObject | null'.
      Type '(event:MouseEvent) =>void' is not assignable to type 'EventListner'. 
        Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent': altKey, button, buttons, clientX and, 21 more.
```

I could fix this by changing `event:MouseEvent` to `event:Event` in the function definition. But then I get-

```
Property clientX does not exist on type 'Event'.
Property clientY does not exist on type 'Event'.
```

What should be the correct types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Node`, that is too basic a type. It does not have type definitions for the given events.

Use `HTMLElement` instead.

Comment: Now I get the `on:panstart` , `on:panmove` does not exists on type `HTMLprops<HTMLDivElement>`.
Should I create a separate post for this?

Comment: You can, but those are **not** standard events. You will have to add your own type definitions that extends the existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the answer, you also need to declare the custom event types in a .d.ts file, for example, you can use the **app.d.ts** provided by the sveltekit and place this code:

```js
declare namespace svelte.JSX {
    export interface HTMLAttributes {
        onpanmove?: (event: CustomEvent) => void
        onpanend?: (event: CustomEvent) => void
        onpanstart?: (event: CustomEvent) => void
    }
}
```

And change the

```
export function pannable(node: Node) {
```

to

```
export function pannable(node: HTMLElement) {
```